# How to find all pairs of two lists, and categorize them without repetitions?

Tags: r, combinatorics

We are preparing for a program where 18 people should discuss topics in a way that in each round they form pairs, and then they switch until everyone has talked to everyone. It means 153 discussions, 9 pairs talking parallelly in each round, for 17 rounds. I tried to formulate a matrix showing who should talk to whom in order to avoid the chaos, but could not succeed. For the sake of simplicity everyone is given a number, so the bottom line is, i would need all pairs of combinations of the numbers from 1 to 18 (did that with combn function), but then these pairs should be rearranged for the 17 round so that each number only appears once per round. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at a simpler problem with `6` persons. The following matrix lists who (rows) is talking to whom (columns) in which round (entry):

[image: Assignment Matrix]

So for example in round 1 (yellow) we have the following pairs:

> (1-2), (3-5), (4-6)

For round 2 (green) we would have:

> (1-3), (2-6), (4-5)

and so on.

Thus, basically we are looking for a symmetric latin square (i.e. in each row and in each column each entry appears only once, cf. [Latin Squares on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)).

The latin square in the box can be easily generated via an addition table:

```
inner_ls <- function(k) {
  res <- outer(0:(k-1), 0:(k-1), function(i, j) (i + j) %% k)
  ## replace zeros by k
  res[res == 0] <- k
  ## replace diagonal by NA
  diag(res) <- NA
  res
}

inner_ls(5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    1   NA    3    4    5
# [3,]    2    3   NA    5    1
# [4,]    3    4    5   NA    2
# [5,]    4    5    1    2   NA
```

So all is left to append the last row (column) with the missing round number:

```
full_ls <- function(k) {
  i_ls <- inner_ls(k - 1)
  last_row <- apply(i_ls, 1, function(row) {
    rounds <- 1:(k - 1)
    rounds[!rounds %in% row]
  })
  res <- cbind(rbind(i_ls, last_row), c(last_row, NA))
  rownames(res) <- colnames(res) <- 1:k
  res
}

full_ls(6)

#    1  2  3  4  5  6
# 1 NA  1  2  3  4  5
# 2  1 NA  3  4  5  2
# 3  2  3 NA  5  1  4
# 4  3  4  5 NA  2  1
# 5  4  5  1  2 NA  3
# 6  5  2  4  1  3 NA
```

With that you get your assignment matrix as follows:

```
full_ls(18)

#     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
# 1  NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
# 2   1 NA  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  2
# 3   2  3 NA  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  4
# 4   3  4  5 NA  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  6
# 5   4  5  6  7 NA  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  8
# 6   5  6  7  8  9 NA 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4 10
# 7   6  7  8  9 10 11 NA 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5 12
# 8   7  8  9 10 11 12 13 NA 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6 14
# 9   8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 NA 17  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 16
# 10  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  1
# 11 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2 NA  4  5  6  7  8  9  3
# 12 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8  9 10  5
# 13 12 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA  8  9 10 11  7
# 14 13 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 NA 10 11 12  9
# 15 14 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA 12 13 11
# 16 15 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 NA 14 13
# 17 16 17  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 NA 15
# 18 17  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 NA
```